# JAVA - How to get annotations from Annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I want to get annotations from annotation, but the weird thing is I can't get single annotation from annotation instance. How do I solve this? I want to get annotations from this annotation instance.

```
public static void test(Annotation annotation) {
    System.out.println("ValidBoolean annotation len:" + ValidBoolean.class.getAnnotations().length);
    System.out.println(annotation.getClass().getName() + ":" + annotation.getClass().getAnnotations().length);
    if (annotation instanceof ValidBoolean) {
        ValidBoolean validBoolean = (ValidBoolean) annotation;
        System.out.println("[BOOLEAN]" + validBoolean.getClass().getName() + ":" + validBoolean.getClass().getAnnotations().length);
    }
}
```

print result is:

```
ValidBoolean annotation len:3
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28:0
[BOOLEAN]com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28:0
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do:

```
Annotation[] annotationAnnotations = annotation.annotationType().getAnnotations();
```

Generally, [`annotationType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#annotationType--) works such that

```
someClass.getAnnotation(someAnnotationClass).annotationType() == someAnnotationClass
```

So `annotation instanceof ValidBoolean` also implies `annotation.annotationType() == ValidBoolean.class`, thus invoking `.getAnnotations()` on them will lead to the same annotations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like annotation is a proxy object

```
 validBoolean.getClass().getSuperclass().getAnnotations().length
```

Comment: Still not working. Do you know how to get annotation from proxy? I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: I'm still not really understanding this Proxy mechanism. But I can get Annotation real class by `annotation.annotationType()` rather than `annotation.getClass()`, because annotation is just a interface so `annotation.getClass()` will only produce a Java Proxy object!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do

```
TopLevelAnnotation topLevelAnnotation = anything.get.getAnnotation(TopLevelAnnotation.class);
NestedAnnotation nestedAnnotation = topLevelAnnotation.annotationType().getAnnotation(NestedAnnotation.class);
```

Please check

```
/**
 * Returns the annotation type of this annotation.
 * @return the annotation type of this annotation
 */
java.lang.annotation.Annotation#annotationType()
```

in java.lang.annotation.Annotation